# Google analytics granting access

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

We wanted to share Read & Analyze access of some Account to some another Google User and in order to do it we've followed [this](https://www.contradodigital.com/resources/how-to-grant-someone-access-to-a-google-analytics-account/#.WQL8kYmGPGI) guide.

User to which access was shared received email: 
`We want to alert you that you have been granted the following access: Read & Analyze... Please log in to Analytics at http://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ to access this account.`

However when user is logged in Accounts and properties menus there is no new web site statistics available.

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong with this scenario?

Comment: have you taken a look at the official instructions from Google? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en

Comment: Is the user unable to see new website statistics? Or your profiles? Does the user (or yourselves) use Google360?

Comment: Thanks guys for suggesting! Seems resolved this problem. For some purpose access was shared only on property level and I haven't seen statistics. When it was shared on account level it's working fine.Have no clue why it didn't work on property level.